# Вопросы к команде StackOverflow

Tags: обсуждение

Есть возможность задать вопросы для одного из управляющих сообществом SO: [@Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9).
Ожидается видеочат (на английском) с интервьюированием посредством нашего управляющего [@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky).

Предлагаю всем заинтересованным сформулировать ниже свои вопросы.
Или хотя бы идеи, из которых можно сделать вопросы.

Comment: Откуда инфа, мой робоподобный друг?

Comment: @alexolut, от Николаса. В чате обсуждали и я решил вынести вопрос из нашего камерного привилегированного меньшинства на общий суд :)

Comment: Ну вот ссылочку на чат было бы хорошо иметь. Авось некоторые и о чате узнают так :)

Comment: @alexolut, спешл фо ю: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37508756#37508756

Comment: Рекурсивненько получилось как-то.

Comment: @alexolut, я хотел этого.

Answer (score 8):

1. [Недавно вышло новое мобильное приложение для Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/). Будет ли они поддерживать сайты Stack Overflow на других языках, в частности на русском?
2. Что, по Вашему мнению, является наиболее вредной привычкой активных участников SO, и почему? (Иными словами: что бы Вы изменили в их поведении на сайте, если бы могли?)
3. Вы однажды обрисовали свои предпочтения в отношении напитков: 
   [джин для веселья, виски для общительности, пиво для задумчивости, водка для серьёзности, вода - чтобы проснуться](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/939027#939027). Какие сорта пива и водки больше всего подходят для серьёзных размышлений?

Comment: Отличные вопросы! Спасибо! Первый, правда к Эбби.

Comment: Приложение не будет поддерживать сайты Stack Overflow на других языках, специально ведь для Stack Overflow другое оформление сделали.

Comment: Ничего себе, дизайн сменили.

Answer (score 4):

У меня есть группа в VK, посвященная определенному софту. На SO есть сайт по этому софту, но он, разумеется, на английском. Большая часть сообщений в этой группе - вопросы, и само собой, я мечтаю перевести их в формат SO. Но вот проблема: даже если SO [даст возможность создавать узконаправленные рускоязычные сообщества на area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack), у меня есть большие сомнения, что люди будут переходить на SO, чтобы задать вопрос, вместо того, чтобы задать его прямо в VK. В связи с этим вопросы:

1. Планируется ли расширение SO в соц.сети, в частности, в виде приложений для VK?
2. Сможем ли мы увидеть новые сообщества на русском языке?

Comment: Отличный вопрос! Спасибо! К слову, подскажите, пробовали ли вы сделать приложение для VK для Stack Overflow на русском? Было бы крайне интересно посмотреть или поучаствовать в проекте, если он с открытым кодом!

Comment: Я думал над этим, но в моих меркантильных целях это бессмысленно, тк нужно отдельное сообщество на русском языке, которое [создать нельзя](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack).

Comment: Интересно, а какие действия, на ваш взгляд, пользователям ВК было бы удобнее выполнять на ruSO через приложение в соцсети?

Comment: @D-side Вы, наверное, знаете, что у групп в VK есть возможность добавлять «приложения сообществ» - у которых есть кнопка, с произвольным текстом. Представьте текст на ней - «задать вопрос», которая будет вести в мобильное приложение.

Comment: Закрой группу и будут переходить.

Comment: Alex78191 ну во первых всегда через такой фильтр кто-то не пройдет. Например, украинцев стало на четверть меньше после закрытия VK. Ну и конечно, пока некуда переходить=)

Answer (score 4):

Было бы чудесно обсудить вопрос тревог в чате и их обработку.
Подробнее [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5452/207618).

[@Nofate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate) [высказал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5452/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5#comment20434_5452) интересную мысль:

> Было бы разумно для чата задавать титульный язык и показывать тревоги из этого чата только тем, у кого такой язык выставлен в профиле (языков в профиле должно быть допустимо несколько).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258676/282647

Comment: @Grundy, там немного другая идея обсуждалась: показывать тревоги в рамках сайта (чаты привязаны к сайтам). Я предложил дать пользователю самому выбирать интересующие языки (как избранные метки).