# Эффективность анонимной модерации сообщений в чате

Tags: обсуждение

День добрый.

Не так давно произошли события (не суть важно какие), которые показали что система анонимной проверки флагов в чате работает плохо, по крайней мере для русского сообщества.

Причина представляется мне в том, что без знания контекста, окружения, темы, банально языка, невозможно эффективно выполнять проверку, а иногда и просто неудобно выходит: кусочек может оскорбить, задеть чьи-то чувства, хотя на деле обращение было не к проверяющему, так что оскорбления в принципе не было.

Хотелось бы узнать позицию официальной власти и соображения всех, кто хочет соображать на тему.

**UPD:**

На близкую тему уже был вопрос: "[non inclusive language в комментариях и вопросах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4481/207618)".

**UPD_2:**

Я напоминаю что это вопрос не о моей персоне, а о проблеме модерации без понимания что вообще происходит из-за незнания языка.
Вопрос на [главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273259/340911).

Comment: Если Вы добавите ссылок из чата, то и официальную позицию там найдете, кмк.

Comment: @alexolut, там только объяснение что нельзя это говорить, а то кто-то может оскорбится. И ни слова ответа на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Было бы разумно для чата задавать титульный язык и показывать тревоги из этого чата только тем, у кого такой язык выставлен в профиле (языков в профиле должно быть допустимо несколько).

Comment: @Nofate, какая замечательная мысль. Надо на конференции с Шогом задать вопрос на эту тему.

Comment: @Aid, на русском :-D

Comment: @Grundy, конечно, раз они жалуются на наши **внутренние** разговоры, то и мы будем так же жаловаться на нашем **внутреннем** языке.

Comment: если с правильным контекстом вы не считаете какое-либо сообщение достойным удаления, то приведите контекст прямо в вопросе и само сообщение. Ваша ссылка ведёт к обсуждению последствий (то есть это не начало, а скорее уже конец обсуждения). Не зная, что было сказано (даже без контекста), сложно судить адекватная реакция на флаг была или нет.

Comment: @jfs, это начало обсуждения, само спорное сообщение выжгли калёным железом. Там была шутка "я за равные права. Среди белых :)".

Comment: флаг оправдан, сообщение удалено, пользователя банить не нужно, если это не регулярные проявления -- всё работает как положено.

Comment: @jfs, напишите ответом что Вы считаете хорошим и оправданным. Почему Вы считаете подобные шутки неприемлемыми и пр.

Comment: @Aid: вы выбрали это сообщение в качестве доказательства, что система флагов плохо работает -- вам и доказывать, что пример является хорошим и оправданным, что такие шутки приемлимы итд.

Comment: @jfs, Вам не интересно/не хотите почитать чат для понимая ситуации - Ваше право, проходите мимо, не засоряйте комментарии.

Comment: @Aid: чат я читал. Не нужно необоснованных утверждений делать.  Если вам лень краткое информативное резюме ваше позиции записать, то незачем вам вообще обсуждение здесь создавать и  тратить время людей.

Comment: @jfs, раз Вам не нравится - минусите и проходите.

Comment: Шутка действительно расистская.

Русское сообщество ничем не отличается от любого другого в этом смысле. 

Флаг был оправданно подтверждён. Система анонимной модерации сообщений сработала как и должна была.

Answer (score 5):

А зачем вообще расистские (и любые другие противоречащие правилам, разжигающие рознь) шутки было постить? Почему они могут быть допустимыми? И как контекст это может оправдать? Я не считаю что это необходимо допускать, вне зависимости от контекста. Неужели нельзя тем, кому этого не достаёт, нельзя найти другое место для таких "шуточек", а здесь так не делать?

Хотите попробуйте предложить на главной мете расистские шутки оценивать только "в контексте", и только модераторам владеющим данным языком. Я думаю, это предложение "оценят по достоинству". А то видимо вас "не так поняли".

---

Возможно я не прав, выложите, пожалуйста, весь спорный фрагмент с "контекстом". Может чьи-то невинные шутки несправедливо "репрессировали".

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на **UPD_2**. Что у меня было - это лишь пример, а не причина написать "поплакаться". Такое ощущение что ссылку на чат с обсуждением никто не читает, чтобы понять суть.

Comment: @Aid Я видел этот вопрос на мете и я его поддерживаю. Но я так понимаю вы ведёт речь за этот конкретный пример. Поэтому с jfs  согласен. Если вы считаете уместной шутку про "равные права среди белых", и считаете, что русскоязычные модераторы 100% отнеслись к ней благосклонно, то это странно.

Comment: Пусть так, я не спорю уже. Но вопрос не в этом же, пример для... примера.

Comment: @Aid Выберите тогда более достойный пример или исключите его вовсе. Этот пример скорее наталкивает на мысль, что это не так и плохо, что сообщество модерируется нерусскоязычными модераторами. Дело в том, что [второй ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273261/346987) к вопросу на мете делает оговорку на случай когда модератору с помощью машинного перевода очевидно, что за ситуация. И это, вполне возможно, можно и отнести как раз к этому случаю.

Comment: Как пожелаете, уже исключил. Непонятно, конечно, что обидного, но...

Comment: @Aid Для меня лично ничего. Вообще. Но просто расизм и шуточки на эту тему здесь неуместны по правилам. И я просто не вижу причин менять или нарушать эти правила. И считаю справедливым и удаления  подобных сообщений тоже. И наказания за несоблюдения правил.