# Участники имеют право высказывать своё мнение?

Tags: обсуждение

Похожий вопрос уже [задавался на днях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5457/213987).

Вопрос получил большое число минусов и практически такое же большое число плюсов: [я вижу](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38129038#38129038)  причину этого в следующем:

> Мне не очень нравятся такие вопросы, на которых большое число минусов
>   и примерно такое же число плюсов. Очень похоже, будто вопрос состоит
>   из двух половинок, при этом плюсы идут на одну часть вопроса
>   (например, на отвлечённо-благое "все имеют право высказывать своё
>   мнение"), а минусы -- другую ("давайте разбаним Squidward"). Я бы
>   предпочёл в таком случае увидеть вопрос разделённым на две части. В
>   первой части обсуждать вопрос про уставы монастыря, во второй -
>   частный кейс модерирования

Именно поэтому я хочу ещё раз поднять этот же самый вопрос, по возможности исключив из него всякую конкретику с блокировкой какого–либо участника.

Формулировка вопроса вынесена в заголовок, для меня это достаточно очевидный и тривиальный вопрос по этике, но раз возникают вопросы то распишу более подробно:

1. Можно ли в ответах к вопросу (в первую очередь -- на мете, где обсуждаются вопросы о жизни сообщества, а не конкретные вопросы по техническим вопросам на основном сайте) высказывать любое собственное мнение, даже не относящееся к вопросу?
2. Аналогичный вопрос относится и к чату. Там нет формата "вопрос-ответ", но текущая реализация механизма тревог (тревоги [часто видят](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5452/%d0%ad%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5#comment20434_5452) пользователи, не знающие русский язык) заставляет выделить явно этот вопрос отдельно.

Comment: по первому пункту - нет, комментарии к вопросу - не слишком подходящее для этого место. на такие комментарии положено ставить тревогу "too chatty", которая у нас внезапно переведена как "слишком слабо обоснованный"

Comment: @PashaPash, _слишком слабо обоснованный_ - так вот для чего нужна эта тревога!

Comment: @Grundy да, внезапно. стоит переименовать, но никто не знает во что именно

Comment: @PashaPash "трёп не по делу"

Comment: @Nofate "за базар ответишь!"

Comment: Я могу писать своё мнение на любую тему в любом комментарии или ответе на вопрос. Другой пользователь может пометить мое творчество флажком тревоги. Модератор может это удалить. "И Женя может лететь в Ленинград."

Comment: Ваш пост тоже подходит под это определение: предлагать разделять посты и обсудить конкретный вопрос про высказывание мнения =)

Answer (score 8):

Есть хорошая фраза про то, что свобода человека безгранична и заканчивается лишь там, где начинается свобода другого человека.

Положим, некто является каннибалом (ну или мягче -- садистом), то может ли он полностью реализовать свою свободу делать всё, что ему захочется? Доколе это не помешает другим людям реализовывать свои свободы -- пожалуй, может.

Человек -- существо социальное, и в социуме выработались некоторые правила, чтобы мы жили друг с другом более-менее спокойно, а не поубивали друг друга. Собственно, все эти правила этики и морали на мой взгляд сводятся к ограничению внутривидовой агрессии. Агрессия -- это именно причинение вреда другому человеку, а не мягкий термин из психологии "движение по направлению к". На агрессию (пусть даже и "всего лишь" вербальную: слово тоже может ранить) налагается множество запретов -- как в любых морально-этических системах и религиях, так и в уголовном кодексе.

Когда вы приходите в какое-либо место -- там обязательно будут некоторые правила, неважно писаные или неписаные:

> Пользователи имеют право высказывать своё мнение при условии [соблюдения правил сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Куда бы вы ни пришли - монастырей без устава не существует, правила -- это вещь, которая фиксирует некоторый набор прав и обязанностей, то как они соотносятся. Вы вряд ли где-то найдёте в правилах письменно зафиксированное "право высказывать своё мнение означает ответственность за свои слова", это такая вещь, которая относится к уровню негласных правил, которую можно назвать культурой.

Дальше либо у вас "по Оруэллу" сработает автоматический "самостоп" на некоторые свои действия до того, как вы захотите реализовать свои свободы, либо вы их реализуете, но понесёте некоторое наказание, которое заставит вас поменять своё поведение (в пределе -- изгнание из сообщества, символическая смерть)

Хорошо ли это или плохо? Собственно, мораль -- это просто система, некоторый набор правил. С точки зрения индивидуума она плоха, так как ограничивает его свободу (скажем, говорить что хочешь и не нести за это никакой ответственности -- или скажем, убивать всех обидчиков). С точки зрения выживания вида мораль именно тем и хороша, что не даёт самоистребиться, пусть и в угоду некоторому ограничению.

Длинное и нудное теоретическое вступление закончено, по более конкретным вопросам.

1. Ответы на вопросы на мете как правило описывают собственное мнение
   отвечающего (и сообщество выражает своё согласие/несогласие в форме
   upvote/downvote на конкретный ответ), многие авторы пытаются также
   обобщить мнение сообщества.

   Мы приветствуем, когда ответы отвечают
   на поставленный вопрос, а не рассказывают о том, как корабли
   бороздят просторы большого театра -- это очевидно.

   Также очевидно
   для меня, что ответы должны соответствовать правилам сайта -- как
   уже прописанным явно, так и неписанным правилам, т.н. "духу закона,
   а не его букве".

   Суть принципа "be nice" описана письменно и может
   быть непонятна лишь людям другой культуры, которые просят уточнить и
   вот этот момент и вот это и ещё вот это непрописано. Пожалуйста,
   различайте уровень культуры (достаточно общие правила) от уровня
   конкретного списка слов, которые запрещены к употреблению на сайте.
   (И если такого списка нет -- то умейте без списка ориентироваться,
   что приветствуется, а что нет)
2. Чат -- это то же самое место, что и сайт, его подраздел. В целом на
   нём действуют те же самые правила, что и на общем сайте. (Очень жаль,
   что у нас до сих пор нет [правил для общего
   чата](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5288/213987), а также
   избранных модераторов чата, надеюсь, что в этом направлении будут
   изменения).

   Тот факт, что мы по некоторым техническим особенностям
   движка находимся в более широком культурном контексте не должен
   вызывать стремления огородиться и замкнуться. Культура stackoverflow
   основана на знаниях и если вы тянетесь к знаниям и хотите расти над
   собой -- то стоит привыкать и к более высоким стандартам в области
   культуры, без которых невозможен свободный обмен знаниями.

И напоследок уровень совсем конкретных вопросов. Я озвучивал своё мнение по поводу конкретного инцидента (см. часть [скажем тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=38104888#38104888)), очень подробно дал ответ PashaPash.

Дополню вот каким моментом. В конкретном ответе Squidward по факту постулировалось отрицание правил сайта ("а я говорю вот так и буду делать то, что я захочу, наплевав на ваши правила и какую-то чужую культуру")

Видите ли, есть два явления, внешне похожих похожих до степени смещения в двух разных культурах. В обоих культурах если у вас большая репутация то вы автоматически обладаете некоторым подтверждённым авторитетом. При этом в одной культуре сквозь пальцы смотрят на некоторую дедовщину со стороны авторитетов (общение свысока на новичков сообщества, пока они не получат высокую репутацию), в другой культуре подобное общение выглядит неприемлемым (сколько бы ты ни заработал репутации на ответах - это не повод общаться с новичками несколько свысока).

И это в общем-то и есть та самая скрытая часть айсберга, которая в пять раз больше наблюдаемой части.

Comment: [Да ну?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) И вообще, это тут совершенно не при чём.

Comment: tl;dr..........

Comment: аргумент про каннибалов не имеет отношения к вопросу о высказывании своего мнения

Comment: @Qwertiy То, что это оффтопик и такие вопросы здесь неуместны, подтверждает историческая блокировка данного вопроса.

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow не тот ресурс на котором можно выражать свое мнение не по теме. Он создан для оперативного получения ответа на вопрос, а не рассуждений о смысле жизни, свободы, принципов. Даже на ресурсах созданных для этого можно увидеть комментарии в стиле: "Да кому вообще нужно твое мнение!(читай как: Эй, да ты же оскорбил меня и единомышленников, не закрыл бы ты варешку)". Сюда люди приходят за ответами на свой вопрос.

Недавно задавали вопрос о дискуссиях, где победили сторонники движения против них. Рассуждать и спорить - это на хабре. Здесь нету места мнениям, т.к. сюда не приходят за ним.

Comment: Это конечно круто, но вопрос о мете, а не об основном сайте.

Comment: Это мало что меняет.

Comment: На хабре за собственное мнение, особенно если оно не совпадает с генеральной линией партии, молча напихают в карму до глубокого ухода в минус. Самое нетерпимое интернет-сообщество, которое когда-либо мне встречалось.

Comment: Общество всегда нетерпимое, просто сам сайт дает им инструмент для подобного "изгнания" или более романтичного "правосудия".