# Выпуск №3 с @Shog9 28.07.2017 21:17. Присоединяйтесь!

Tags: поддержка, видеочат

С радостью спешу пригласить всех участников сообщества присоединиться к видеочату 28.07.2017. Мы начнем трансляцию, когда в Санкт–Петербурге будет 21:17. Гостем третьего выпуска будут «живая легенда» MSE – [@Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9).

Shog9 – один из первых участников сообщества Stack Overflow на английском. С самых первых дней Shog9 интересовался не только самим программированием, но и развитием сообщества еще на UserVoice, а затем на Мете. В первой половине 2011 года, Shog9 [присоединился](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/25/welcome-valued-associate-josh-heyer/) к команде в роли управляющего сообществом. Shog9 работает удаленно из Колорадо.

Видео будет доступно в реальном времени на канале сообщества: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dfcXzZ6I3g.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы гостям!

Главная цель видеочата – узнать друг друга поближе. Расскажите, гостям о том, что вам интересно в них! Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы участникам выпуска!

Ваши вопросы участникам выпуска вы можете задать в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) или в [специальном вопросе на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5241/). Обязательно, задавая вопрос в чате, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky` и/или имя участника, кому вопрос адресован , чтобы я (мы) мог своевременно отреагировать на ваш вопрос. Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос к участникам заранее мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com).

Comment: _по Санкт–Петербургу_ - а по москве во сколько? :-D

Comment: А это не совсем [дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5241/186999)?

Comment: @Grundy это не дубликат вовсе! В данном вопросе есть ссылка на указанный вами. Этот вопрос – продолжение предыдущего и по совместительству анонс.

Comment: Ага, я ее сразу не заметил, просто и тут: _Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы гостям!_ и `Shog9`, и в том вопросе тоже

Comment: А он будет по-русски шпрехать? или google translate будет выручать?

Comment: @Grundy не вижу неточностей, так как _Ваши вопросы участникам выпуска вы можете задать в чате сообщества или в специальном вопросе на Мете (ссылка на предыдущий вопрос)._ Выпуск, с очень большой вероятностью, как минимум на половину, будет на английском языке.

Comment: А я что-то не понял, он будет один? или будет еще кто-то все-таки?

Comment: @Grundy еще буду я время от времени.

Comment: Не, ну эт-то понятно, ты не считаешься, как ведущий :-)

Comment: @Grundy Время как-то непонятно указано. Я исправил, чтобы самому не запутаться.

Comment: @Squidward, ты ходишь по _очень_ тонкому льду :-D :-D :-D

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а можно добавить оповещение о начале в чате? А то в прошлый раз, как-то тихо все началось, я полчаса где-то пропустил с начала

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Часовой пояс называется "Московское время (MSK)", поэтому корректно говорить "по Москве". Ваша формулировка вводит в заблуждение и может создать впечатление, что событие каким-то образом привязано к конкретному городу. Не говоря уж о том, что не все осведомлены в географии и в курсе часовых поясов в каждом городе.

Comment: @Squidward Поправил указание времени, чтобы не вводить никого в заблуждение (речь, конечно же, о городе, не о часовом поясе).

Comment: @Grundy Прикрутил [событие в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22462/stack-overflow--?tab=schedule).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а там по идее регистрироваться надо?

Comment: @Grundy Ага. Видимо, это какие–то внутренние механизмы (я ранее данный функционал не использовал). Видео будет доступно всем в реальном времени «без регистрации и смс».

Comment: можно подробнее о формате? live stream на youtube? Вопросы на любом языке, адресовать @NicolasChabanovsky заранее и/или в живую в http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow-- ?

Comment: @jfs Формат видео в реальном времени на YouTube. Вопросы в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), на самом деле, лучше задавать сразу на английском как мне, так и для Shog9. Вопросы на русском также не останутся без внимания. Если у вас уже появился вопрос, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его ответом в [специальном вопросе на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5241/6).